# Django upgrade from 1.4 to 1.5.4 broke submit_line.html admin template

Tags: python, django

I recently upgraded a site from 1.4 to 1.5.4, and it seems like in the submit_line.html template, "original" is not set.
This line fails for that reason:

```
{% if show_delete_link %}
<p class="deletelink-box">
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'delete' original.pk|admin_urlquote %}"
class="deletelink">{% trans "Delete" %}
</a></p>{% endif %}
```

I've traced this back to the change_form admin template (django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html), which also uses "original", and successfully expands the exact same context object.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you show the traceback..??

Comment: Reverse for 'INVALID_TEMPLATE_STRING_opts' with arguments '(u'INVALID_TEMPLATE_STRING_original.pk',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID set in your settings file? The Django documentation [recommends against enabling TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables):

> While TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID can be a useful debugging tool, it is a bad idea to turn it on as a ‘development default’.
>
> Many templates, including those in the Admin site, rely upon the silence of the template system when a non-existent variable is encountered. If you assign a value other than '' to TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID, you will experience rendering problems with these templates and sites.

Comment: This is unrelated. The error is that "original" is not set, and I proved this without using TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID. This is an unrelated tangent.

Comment: The stacktrace showing INVALID_TEMPLATE_STRING above was a red herring  – that's not a standard Django error

Comment: Again, this is unrelated. The problem is that "original" is not set, and this handy debug tool makes this blatantly obvious, instead of showing an obscure stack trace. Looking at the template syntax, you'll notice that it clearly will crash if "original" is not set. This is the precise issue, nothing else. Nothing displays the precise issue better than this handy TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID tool.

Comment: The useless stack trace:  `code AttributeError at /admin/auth/user/73/
 
 'str' object has no attribute 'app_label'
 
 Request Method:  GET
 Request URL:  https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/admin/auth/user/73/
 Django Version:  1.5.4
 Exception Type:  AttributeError
 Exception Value:  
 
 'str' object has no attribute 'app_label'
 
 Exception Location:  /opt/xxxxxxxxxx/.virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_urls.py in admin_urlname, line 9
 Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
 Python Version:  2.6.6
 Python Path: `

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wasn't registering the model with the admin. ie: I forgot to add the following in my `model.py`

`admin.site.register(Post)` where Post is a Model